Flutter Dart unexpected sort behavior
When I try to sort a list of ints with the length of the list starting from 34 and use a compare function that returns 0, it gives some unexpected results:
Here's the code:
  final nums = List.generate(34, (i) => i);
  final sortedNums = nums.sorted((a, b) => 0);

  print('nums: $nums');
  print('sortedNums: $sortedNums');

Here's the result:
nums: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33]
sortedNums: [11, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 33, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 21]

Look at how the position of elements at index 0 and 11 as well as elements at index 21 and 33 are changed!

See how the return value represents the comparison here

check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/sort.html - they say: "A Comparator may compare objects as equal (return zero), even if they are distinct objects. The sort function is not guaranteed to be stable, so distinct objects that compare as equal may occur in any order in the result:" - there is an example showing the issue: final numbers = <String>['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']; numbers.sort((a, b) => a.length.compareTo(b.length)); print(numbers); // [one, two, four, three] OR [two, one, four, three]

The default Dart sorting algorithm is not stable, it does not guarantee to preserve the order of elements that compare equal (compare returns 0). The behavior looks stable up to 34 elements because the library uses a different (stable) algorithm for short lists, but then switches to using something like quick-sort to split the original into shorter runs that are then sorted recursively. Quick-sort splitting is not stable.

The custom comparison function (a, b) => 0 essentially tells the sorting algorithm that all elements are equal, which can lead to an unstable sorting result where the original order of equal elements is not preserved. To achieve a stable sort (where the original order of equal elements is maintained), you'll need to implement a custom comparison function that properly compares elements based on your desired sorting criteria.
For example, if you want to sort the list in ascending order based on the values of the elements, you can use the following code:
void main() {
    final nums = List.generate(34, (i) => i);
    nums.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));

    print('nums: $nums');
}


Thanks. Could you please provide the link to your quoted text?!
And I know that (a, b) => 0 doesn't make any sense and we can simply ignore it if we don't want the list to be sorted, but I made this example from a more complex scenario in one of the projects that I work on. In that project, sometimes it's inevitable to prevent such a case, so I just wanted to know what's the real issue.
I tried the same example in Java, but it works fine, so I think it's some implementation detail in the Dart language itself.

the sort is not promised to be stable.  How hard is that to understand?
